# Renaming .txt files with string contained within the file

Tags: awk, ubuntu-18.04

I have a folder containing .txt files that each contain 1 line of text. The files are named as such:

file_1.txt
file_2.txt
file_3.txt
file_4.txt

In each file, there is a line of text that has the text transcript of a corresponding audio file plus the name of the audio file in brackets, like this:

`Some text here (31ca4d158eaef166c37a_18.87_27.76)`

For each file, I need to rename it to the string contained within brackets in the file. I have been able to extract the string in brackets using the following code:

```
awk -F'[()]' '{print $2}' file_*.txt
```

This gives me a list of all the strings contained within brackets in each .txt file, but I have not been able to use this information to rename all of the files. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This has been part of a multi-step process, and solutions that have worked for me have mainly been in awk, but I would be happy to hear solutions using other languages, especially if they are built-in to Ubuntu 18.04 (my OS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for file in file_*.txt;do mv -- "$file" "$(awk -F'[()]' '{print $2}' "$file")";done
```

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help. In case you need clarification, just ask